# React Native - Refresh top component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I set up a NativeEventEmitter and added a listener to it in my React Native app outside of any Component in `index.ios.js`. The listener's callback method modifies the app's global dict of localized strings which are used throughout the app's UI. I've used the [ReactNativeLocalization library](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) to display localized strings.

I need the callback to somehow refresh the UI to display the new strings, regardless of which components are currently on screen.

Here is the code for my listener:

```
global.localizedStrings = new LocalizedStrings({});
const myModuleEvt = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.StringsEmitter);
myModuleEvt.addListener( 'LocalizedStringsUpdated', (newStrings) => {
  localizedStrings = new LocalizedStrings(newStrings);
  // TODO force update current screen
});
```

Any ideas how that could be achieved? Thanks